# Application Loader reports missing code-signing certificate when certificate is definitely included

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

I am having trouble uploading using Application Loader. The message I get is this:
[image: Xcode snapshot]

I have:

- Deleted the certificates from Keychain Access
- Deleted the provisioning profiles from the folder I keep them in
- Online (developer.apple.com/account/ios), I have created new:
- - Development certificate
- - App ID
- - Provisioning profile
- I have then opened Xcode and using:
  Xcode->Preferences->Account->View Details...->Refresh
  ​I have refreshed the list of provisioning profiles on my machine. This is reflected in the profile manager online.

I still get the message in the dialog above when attempting to upload.

Can anyone help me? Did I miss a step or is there a folder I need to clean out that I may not know about?

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding your using wrong Profile.check following things

You need to install Production certificate and Provision certificate from your apple developer membership latest.

Once you done above thing go to xcode check Bundle Identifier,Version that all need to match with your Identifier name (from member center) and Version (from meta Data).

Go to Build setting select Provisioning profile select your distribution in it.After that code Signing Identity select "Automatic".Than create ipa file.

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

download your new certificates and provisioning profile from member center and double click on them to store in keychain access and try again.