# Invalid provisioning profile, Missing code signing certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store

I have built my app using flutter and completed testing. I use automatic signing in Xcode and it creates a development provisioning profile.

I am aware I need a distribution provisioning profile to publish in app store so in Xcode again i am able to automatically create this under Preferences-Accounts-Manage Certificates.

Now I have two provisioning certificate under my account one created automatically and the other I have created for distribution.

I am using transporter to submit to the to the App store. However this fails with Error Itmd-90161 Invalid provisioning profile.

I tried to delete the development profile but xcode keeps recreating it automatically. I have also looked through those with similar issues such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716549/application-loader-reports-missing-code-signing-certificate-when-certificate-is) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960751/error-code-90161-invalid-provisioning-profile) but not able to get a clear solution to this problem now for days.

Help is much appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: You can use Xcode to submit your app to app store. Maybe that will work.

Comment: Thanx @Pranav am using xcode to submit. Transporter seems to have issues yet it was designed to be easy